# Jenkins Sshagent plugin in slave not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the `sshagent` and credentials plugin to execute couple of git commands on a remote repo in a jenkins  pipeline script .

I am trying to do this checkout some files from a large repo . This runs on a docker slave .

```
sshagent(['a5f11347-dff6-4586-ae77-34adeffb0063']) {
  script {
    sh 'git archive --remote=ssh://git@git.comp.com/something.git HEAD Jenkinsfile | tar -x'
    sh 'git archive --remote=ssh://git@git.comp.com/something.git  HEAD:pipeline/ | tar -x;'
     }
    }
```

But it fails with a hostkey verification failed error. Any insight on why this is failing .

If i do a

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${BRANCH_NAME}"]],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
     extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 0, noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: true],
                 [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: true],
                 [$class: 'SparseCheckoutPaths', sparseCheckoutPaths: [[path: 'Jenkinsfile'], [path: 'pipeline/*']]]],
                 submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'a5f11347-dff6-4586-ae77-34adeffb0063',
                  url: 'ssh://git@git.comp.com/something.git']]])
```

it works fine ,but the large repo is fetched ,which i want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the host key verification problem, you need to add the host key for `git.comp.com` to your SSH `known_hosts` file. Try integrating the following command in your Jenkins script *before* the `sshagent` block:

```
ssh-keyscan git.comp.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This worked for me.

See [Jenkins ssh-agent starts and then stops immediately in pipeline build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49275434/7269988) for more info.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20704268)

Comment: Content revised. Thank you for informing me.