# Jenkins ssh-agent starts and then stops immediately in pipeline build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-agent

I have a simple jenkins pipeline build, this is my jenkinsfile:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('deploy-staging') {
            when {
                branch 'staging'
            }
            steps {
                sshagent(['my-credentials-id']) {
                    sh('git push joe@repo:project')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using sshagent to push to a git repo on a remote server. I have created credentials that point to a private key file in Jenkins master ~/.ssh.

When I run the build, I get this output (I replaced some sensitive info with *'s):

```
[ssh-agent] Using credentials *** (***@*** ssh key)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-cjbm7oVQaJYk/agent.11558
SSH_AGENT_PID=11560
$ ssh-add ***
Identity added: ***
[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 11560 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[TDBNSSBFW6JYM3BW6AAVMUV4GVSRLNALY7TWHH6LCUAVI7J3NHJQ] Running shell script
+ git push joe@repo:project
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

As you can see, the ssh-agent starts, stops immediately after and then runs the git push command. The weird thing is it did work correctly once but that seemed completely random.

I'm still fairly new to Jenkins - am I missing something obvious? Any help appreciated, thanks.

edit: I'm running a multibranch pipeline, in case that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git inside docker inside Jenkins pipeline doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870282/git-inside-docker-inside-jenkins-pipeline-doesnt-work)

Comment: As @herm pointed out, it wasn't the ssh-agent stopping that is the cause of the issue. (I suspect that it stops after it's goal is accomplished and it is no longer needed?) Please consider giving your question a new title so that it isn't misleading to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue though it was inside a docker container.
The logs gave the impression that ssh-agent exits too early but actually the problem was that I had forgotten to add the git server to known hosts.

I suggest ssh-ing onto your jenkins master and trying to do the same steps as the pipeline does with ssh-agent (the cli). Then you'll see where the problem is.

E.g:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/yourKey
git clone
```

As explained [on help.github.com](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)

Update:
Here a util to add knownHosts if not yet added:

```
/**
 * Add hostUrl to knownhosts on the system (or container) if necessary so that ssh commands will go through even if the certificate was not previously seen.
 * @param hostUrl
 */
void tryAddKnownHost(String hostUrl){
    // ssh-keygen -F ${hostUrl} will fail (in bash that means status code != 0) if ${hostUrl} is not yet a known host
    def statusCode = sh script:"ssh-keygen -F ${hostUrl}", returnStatus:true
    if(statusCode != 0){
        sh "mkdir -p ~/.ssh"
        sh "ssh-keyscan ${hostUrl} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... that was it! I completely forgot about adding to known hosts. I also have no idea why I didn't think of replicating the commands myself on the server. Thanks for the suggestion, I'd have probably struggled with that for hours.

Comment: No problem. I strugeled with exactly the same thing (but inside a docker container which was one more source of possible issues) for a day or so. Glad I could help

Comment: Check the update. There you have a util that adds a knownhost only if necessary. This will help you use ssh-agent inside a docker container. Of course it makes you vulnerable to man in the middle....

Comment: Ok cool thanks that's really useful, and yes of course would need to be very careful about how I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using this inside docker, and adding it to my Jenkins master's `known_hosts` felt a bit messy, so I opted for something like this:

1. In Jenkins, create a new credential of type "Secret text" (let's call it `GITHUB_HOST_KEY`), and set its value to be the host key, e.g.:

```sh
# gets the host for github and copies it. You can run this from
# any computer that has access to github.com (or whatever your
# git server is)
ssh-keyscan github.com | clip
```

2. In your Jenkinsfile, save the string to `known_hosts`

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'node:12' } }
    stages {
        stage('deploy-staging') {
            when { branch 'staging' }
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'GITHUB_HOST_KEY', variable: 'GITHUB_HOST_KEY')]) {
                    sh 'mkdir ~/.ssh && echo "$GITHUB_HOST_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
                }
                sshagent(['my-credentials-id']) {
                    sh 'git push joe@repo:project'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures you're using a "trusted" host key.